# The syntax of the command is incorrect while compiling Clang with GCC-4.9.1_x64

Tags: windows, gcc, cmake, clang

After coming across some problems regarding cmake and gcc-4.9.1 on windows system, and spending more than 2 hours of building llvm with clang I got a really nice error that I can't seem to find information on. I've done everything according to documentation and here's the story-teller error message that make gives me:

```
Scanning dependencies of target LTO_exports
[ 69%] Creating export file for LTO
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make[2]: *** [tools/lto/LTO.def] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tools/lto/CMakeFiles/LTO_exports.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

That is all to it, no other detail available at all. I've checked the LTO.def file since it references that. The file contains one single entry: "EXPORTS[CR][LF]". The LTO_exports.dir/all contains the following files:

```
build.make
cmake_clean.cmake
depend.internal
depend.make
DependInfo.cmake
progress.make
```

I haven't touched these files at all. I used the following cmake command before actually using make.

```
C:\LLVM_Binaries>cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/MinGW/bin/make.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\LLVM
```

Also here're the details of gcc g++ and make:
gcc --version

```
gcc (GCC) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

g++ --version

```
g++ (GCC) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

make -v

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
This program is built by Equation Solution <http://www.Equation.com>
for Windows.
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Anyone else experienced this problem and managed to build llvm with clang on 64bit Windows operating system?

@Edit (output of make VERBOSE=1)

```
Scanning dependencies of target LTO_exports
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/LLVM_Binaries'
make -f tools\lto\CMakeFiles\LTO_exports.dir\build.make tools/lto/CMakeFiles/LTO_exports.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `C:/LLVM_Binaries'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\LLVM_Binaries\CMakeFiles
[ 69%] Creating export file for LTO
cd /d C:\LLVM_Binaries\tools\lto && "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo EXPORTS > LTO.def
cd /d C:\LLVM_Binaries\tools\lto && type C:/LLVM/tools/lto/lto.exports >> LTO.def
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make[2]: *** [tools/lto/LTO.def] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/LLVM_Binaries'
make[1]: *** [tools/lto/CMakeFiles/LTO_exports.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/LLVM_Binaries'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you run `make VERBOSE=1` and post the relevant output for the failing command?

Comment: Yeah sure, I can. I'll start it up and hopefully update my original post with the details it gave in the following 2-3hours until it'll crash... It takes some time.

Comment: Updated the original post with the relevant output of make with verbose=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging in this issue quite deeply I've successfully built it. For anyone who might get this error while compiling llvm&clang on windows with gcc: http://reviews.llvm.org/D5476#5e5fbd1d
Of course you can avoid this problem by using the sources from their SVN instead of downloading the latest stable release from http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.5

Answer (score -2):

Did you run the configuration file before running cmake?

```
sh ./configure
```

If that doesn't work, try using the 32 bit version of your compiler. If that works, you can build for 64-bit by compiling a GCC 32-bit cross compiler.

You could also try Cygwin - perhaps that might help. Or if you're really stuck you could go backtracking and run the problematic command from a terminal, not a makefile.

Comment: I actually tried your idea. With 32bit gcc compiler the compilation fails at 35% with a lot of errors but I'm leaving them out as I want to compile using my existing compiler.

Comment: Did you run the config script? It will customize the build process to your GCC.

Comment: Another thing is, are you using command prompt or a terminal emulator (such as MSYS or Cygwin.bat)?

Comment: Simple command window (cmd) I don't have neither msys or cygwin. Of course the sources from the official site had a bug, that it only used cygwin for windows systems - see my answer for the patch.

Comment: Is your copy of GCC from WinBuilds.org or something like that? Try upgrading your GCC to the latest version or use the MinGW or Cygwin GCC ports